# Definition: foci of a quadric

Tags: definition, quadrics

How are the foci of a quadric defined?

By a quadric I mean a set
$$ Q = \left\{ x \in \mathbb R^n \mid x^T A x + 2 b^T x + c = 0 \right\}, $$
where $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ is symmetric and $b\in\mathbb R^n$.

Edit: I ask this questions because I encountered the term "confocal quadrics". And I do not even know what a focus is in general dimensions. Maybe we can assume the most simple form
$$Q=\left\{ x \in\mathbb R^n\mid \frac{x_1^2}{a_1}+\ldots+\frac{x_n^2}{a_n}=1    \right\},$$
where $a_1<\ldots <a_n$.
What are the foci of this quadric?

Comment: i think that you should convert  it into canonical form,by canonical i meant  this  one  http://aix1.uottawa.ca/~jkhoury/quadratic.htm,generally foci should correspond to  eigenvectors of matrix

Comment: Ok this is for quadrics in the plane. And I don't understand how they get the foci in the end (it even seems to be wrong to me)

Comment: Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: For quadric surfaces, there're two focal conics.  See another answer [**here**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19849/definition-of-an-ellipsoid-based-on-its-focal-points/1837886#1837886)