# Find the locus of the vertices of the right circular cones that pass through the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1, z=0$

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections, surfaces

> Prove that the locus of the vertices of the right circular cones that pass through the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1, z=0$ is $\frac{x^2}{a^2-b^2}-\frac{z^2}{b^2}=1, y=0$ or $\frac{y^2}{a^2-b^2}+\frac{z^2}{a^2}=-1, z=0$.

EDIT:

Here $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1, z=0$ is the base of the cone. Let the vertex of the cone be $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$. Let the generator be $$\frac{x-x_1}{l}=\frac{y-y_1}{m}=\frac{z-z_1}{n}.$$

Then $z=0$ implies any point on ellipse be $(x_1-lz_1/n, y_1-mz_1/n,0)$. It lies on the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ then the point satisfies the ellipse we get $$\frac{(nx_1-lz_1)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(ny_1-mz_1)^2}{a^2}=n^2$$

Eliminating $l,m,n$ we get the equation of the cone as $$\frac{1}{a^2}(zx_1-xz_1)^2+\frac{1}{b^2}(zy_1-yz_1)^2=(z-z_1)^2.$$ How to get the locus of vertex $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$?

Edit 2

**How to get the locus of the vertices in the given two forms using purely mathematical way?** 
 I not able to solve the problem. Please help.

Comment: Related: ["What is the cone of the conic section?"](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/887011/409). [My answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/887445/409) gives a geometric solution using [Dandelin Spheres](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dandelin_spheres).

Comment: @DandelinSpheres Would you please provide me the remaining mathematical solution of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your solution has stalled because you haven't incorporated the fact that the cone is *circular*. I'll start from scratch.

As you did, we take the cone's generator to pass through $(x_1, y_1, z_1)$ (with $z_1 \neq 0$), and to have *unit* direction vector $(\ell, m, n)$, so that we can write

$$\frac{x-x_1}{\ell} = \frac{y-y_1}{m} = \frac{z-z_1}{n} = t \tag{1}$$

As the vector has unit length, we have
$$1 = \ell^2 + m^2 + n^2 \quad\to\quad (x-x_1)^2 + (y-y_1)^2 + (z-z_1)^2 = t^2 \tag{2}$$
To ensure circularity, we impose the condition that the generator makes a constant (non-right) angle with some unit *axis* vector, $(p,q,r)$. (We may assume $r\neq 0$, so that the axis is not parallel to the $xy$-plane; otherwise, the intersection with that plane would be a hyperbola.) For this, we need only assume that the dot product of the vectors is some (non-zero) constant:
$$(p, q, r)\cdot (\ell,m,n) = k \neq 0 \quad\to\quad p (x-x_1) + q (y-y_1) + r (z-z_1) = kt \tag{3}$$

Eliminating the parameter $t$ from $(1)$ and $(2)$, by expressing $k^2t^2$ in two ways, gives the equation of a circular cone.
$$k^2\left(\;(x-x_1)^2 + (y-y_1)^2 + (z-z_1)^2\;\right) = \left(\;p (x-x_1) + q (y-y_1) + r (z-z_1)\;\right)^2 \tag{4}$$

The intersection of this cone with the plane $z=0$ has this equation:
$$\begin{align}
0 &= x^2 (k^2 - p^2) + y^2 ( k^2 - q^2 ) - 2 x y p q \\
&-2 x (\; (k^2-p^2) x_1 - p q y_1 - p r z_1\;) \\
&-2 y (\; (k^2-q^2) y_1 - p q x_1 - q r z_1\;) \\
&+ (k^2-p^2) x_1^2 + (k^2-q^2)y_1^2 + (k^2-r^2)z_1^2 - 2 p q x_1 y_1 \\
&- 2 p r x_1 z_1 - 2 q r y_1 z_1 \tag{5}
\end{align}$$

For this to match the target ellipse, the equation must be a scalar multiple, say, with factor $u \neq 0$, of $x^2 b^2 + y^2 a^2 - a^2 b^2 = 0$. That is:
$$\begin{align}
k^2 - p^2 &= u b^2 \tag{6.1}\\
k^2 - q^2 &= u a^2 \tag{6.2}\\
p q &= 0 \tag{6.3}\\
ub^2 x_1 &= p r z_1  \tag{6.4}\\
ua^2 y_1 &= q r z_1  \tag{6.5}\\
ub^2 x_1^2 + ua^2 y_1^2 - (k^2-r^2)z_1^2 &= u a^2 b^2 \tag{6.6}
\end{align}$$
where subsequent equations conveniently incorporate substitutions from previous ones.

From here, eliminating $u$, $k$, $p$, $q$ from the system $(6.x)$ results in the target relations, but the process isn't particularly fun. Things simplify a bit by observing from $(6.3)$ that one of $p$ and $q$ vanishes; by $(6.4)$ or $(6.5)$, this implies that $x_1$ or $y_1$, respectively, also vanishes. (This is how we get the separate loci.) Even so, we can make some interesting progress before splitting into cases.

For instance, it's easy enough to solve $(6.1)$ and $(6.2)$ to get (for $a\neq b$)
$$u = \frac{p^2- q^2}{a^2-b^2} \qquad\qquad k^2 = \frac{a^2 p^2 - b^2 q^2}{a^2-b^2} \tag{7}$$
Then, from $(6.4)$ and $(6.5)$, we calculate thusly,
$$( p^2 - q^2 )r^2 z_1^2 = u^2 (b^4 x_1^2 - a^4 y_1^2) = \frac{( p^2 - q^2 )^2}{(a^2-b^2)^2}\,(b^4 x_1^2 - a^4 y_1^2) \tag{8}$$
so that, dividing-through by $p^2-q^2$ (which safely assumes that one of $p$ and $q$ is non-zero when $a\neq b$), we have
$$r^2 z_1^2 = \frac{u(b^4x_1^2-a^4y_1^2)}{a^2-b^2} \tag{9}$$

Therefore, we may re-write $(6.6)$ ...
$$\begin{align}
ub^2 x_1^2 + ua^2 y_1^2 + r^2 z_1^2 - u a^2 b^2 &= k^2z_1^2 \tag{10.1}\\[6pt]
ub^2 x_1^2 + ua^2 y_1^2 + \frac{u(b^4x_1^2-a^4y_1^2)}{a^2-b^2} - u a^2 b^2 &= k^2z_1^2 \tag{10.2}\\[6pt]
u a^2 b^2\left( \frac{x_1^2 - y_1^2}{a^2-b^2} - 1 \right) &= k^2z_1^2 \tag{10.3}\\[6pt]
\frac{x_1^2 - y_1^2}{a^2-b^2} - \frac{k^2z_1^2}{ua^2b^2} &= 1 \tag{10.4} \\[6pt]
\frac{x_1^2 - y_1^2}{a^2-b^2} - \frac{z_1^2}{a^2b^2}\frac{a^2p^2-b^2q^2}{p^2-q^2} &= 1 \tag{10.5}
\end{align}$$
Finally, we can invoke the cases,

> $$\begin{align}
> p = 0 &\quad\to\quad x_1 = 0 \quad\text{and}\quad \frac{- y_1^2}{a^2-b^2} - \frac{z_1^2}{a^2} = 1 \\[6pt]
> q = 0 &\quad\to\quad y_1 = 0 \quad\text{and}\quad \frac{x_1^2}{a^2-b^2} - \frac{z_1^2}{b^2} = 1
> \end{align}$$

Given how elegant the geometric solution is, I suspect there's a more-clever route through the algebra here, but this is the best I have at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/887445/409), I answer the question ["What is the cone of the conic section?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/887011/409) by considering [Dandelin Spheres](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dandelin_spheres), which are tangent to the cone and to the plane of a conic section; the key fact is that Dandelin Spheres are tangent to the plane of a conic section *at the foci* of that conic.

The figure below, taken from that answer, shows the view of the plane perpendicular to an ellipse through its major axis. The ellipse itself appears only as $\overline{PQ}$ (its major axis) and the Dandelin Spheres have become "Dandelin Circles" $\bigcirc{R}$ and $\bigcirc{R^\prime}$. Point $C$, the apex of the cone, is the intersection of lines through $P$ and $Q$ that are tangent to these circles.

[image]

With that introduction, identifying the locus of $C$ is straightforward. We simply observe that
$$|\overline{CS}| = |\overline{CT}| \quad\to\quad |\overline{CP}|+|\overline{PF}| = |\overline{CQ}| + |\overline{QF}| \tag{$\star$}$$

Writing $m$ and $c$ for the ellipse's major and "focal" radii, $(\star)$ says
$$|\overline{CP}| - |\overline{CQ}| = |\overline{QF}| - |\overline{PF}| = (m+c)-(m-c) = 2c$$

That is, the difference of $C$'s distances from $P$ and $Q$ is a constant, so that $C$ lies on a hyperbola with foci $P$ and $Q$ that passes through $F$ and $F^\prime$. This hyperbola has focal radius $m$, transverse radius $c$, and conjugate radius $n := \sqrt{m^2-c^2}$ (equal to the minor radius of the ellipse). Its equation is

$$\frac{w^2}{c^2} - \frac{z^2}{n^2} = 1 \qquad\to\qquad \frac{w^2}{m^2-n^2} - \frac{z^2}{n^2} = 1 \tag{$\star\star$}$$

where the $w$-axis is horizontal in the figure. That axis is either the $x$-axis or the $y$-axis, according to which of $a$ or $b$ is bigger in the given ellipse equation,
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$$

When $a$ is bigger, $\overline{PQ}$ aligns with the $x$-axis, so the figure shows the $xz$-plane; the locus of $C$ is
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2-b^2} - \frac{z^2}{b^2} = 1, \qquad y=0$$
When $b$ is bigger, $\overline{PQ}$ aligns with the $y$-axis, so the figure shows the $yz$-plane; the locus of $C$ is
$$\frac{y^2}{b^2-a^2} - \frac{z^2}{a^2} = 1, \qquad x=0$$
or, equivalently, with appropriate sign changes,
$$\frac{y^2}{a^2-b^2} + \frac{z^2}{a^2} = -1, \qquad x=0$$

---

**Note.** For the configuration shown in the figure, $C$ is on *one semi-branch* of the hyperbola, the "lower-right". Adjusting $\bigcirc{R}$ and $\bigcirc{R^\prime}$ to appear on the other sides of $\overline{PQ}$, and switching which circle is bigger, allows $C$ to travel throughout the entire hyperbola.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. I am happy. I also request you to help me to solve with the steps I have applied by using purely mathematical technique.

Comment: Geometry **is** "purely mathematical". :) I suppose what you mean is that you want to prove the result specifically using *algebraic* techniques. Okay. I'll have to come back to this at a later time.

Comment: Yes. I want to mean it. Thanks for reply.

Comment: I shall be grateful if you kindly post the answer at your earliest.

Comment: @mathlove I seek your help. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You have a good start of getting an enveloping elliptic cone:

$$\frac{(Z x-X z)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(Y z-Z y)^2}{b^2}=(z-Z)^2$$

Rearrange to

> $$
> \begin{pmatrix}
>   x & y & z
> \end{pmatrix}
> \begin{pmatrix}
>   \frac{Z^2}{a^2} & 0 & -\frac{XZ}{a^2} \\
>   0 & \frac{Z^2}{b^2} & -\frac{YZ}{b^2} \\
>   -\frac{ZX}{a^2} & -\frac{ZY}{b^2} & \frac{X^2}{a^2}+\frac{Y^2}{b^2}-1
> \end{pmatrix}
> \begin{pmatrix}
>   x \\ y \\ z
> \end{pmatrix}+
> 2Zz-Z^2=0$$

Due to circular symmetry of right circular cone, the quadratic terms can be diagonalized into the form of $$\lambda x'^2+\lambda y'^2+\mu z'^2$$

which means the matrix has **two equal eigenvalues**.

That is

$$\det
\begin{pmatrix}
  \frac{Z^2}{a^2}-\lambda & 0 & -\frac{XZ}{a^2} \\
  0 & \frac{Z^2}{b^2}-\lambda & -\frac{YZ}{b^2} \\
  -\frac{ZX}{a^2} & -\frac{ZY}{b^2} & \frac{X^2}{a^2}+\frac{Y^2}{b^2}-1-\lambda
\end{pmatrix}=0$$

has a double root.

> Also the vertex should lie on the mirror plane of the ellipse (i.e. either $X=0$, $Y=0$ or $Z=0$; that's only the case for right circular cone).

**Case I**: $X=0$

$$
\left( \frac{Z^2}{a^2}-\lambda \right)
\left[
  \lambda^2+
  \left( 1-\frac{Y^2+Z^2}{b^2} \right)\lambda-
  \frac{Z^2}{b^2}
\right]=0$$

We have two positive roots and one negative root, both factors share the same root $\lambda=\dfrac{Z^2}{a^2}$.

Now
$$\frac{Z^4}{a^4}+
  \left( 1-\frac{Y^2+Z^2}{b^2} \right) \frac{Z^2}{a^2}-
  \frac{Z^2}{b^2}=0 $$

> $$\frac{Y^2}{a^2-b^2}+\frac{Z^2}{a^2} = -1$$
>
> which is an **imaginary ellipse** provided $a^2 > b^2$.

**Case II**: $Y=0$

$$
\left( \frac{Z^2}{b^2}-\lambda \right)
\left[
  \lambda^2+
  \left( 1-\frac{X^2+Z^2}{a^2} \right)\lambda-
  \frac{Z^2}{a^2}
\right]=0$$

We have two positive roots and one negative root, both factors share the same root $\lambda=\dfrac{Z^2}{b^2}$.

Now
$$\frac{Z^4}{b^4}+
  \left( 1-\frac{X^2+Z^2}{a^2} \right) \frac{Z^2}{b^2}-
  \frac{Z^2}{a^2}
  =0 $$

> $$\frac{X^2}{a^2-b^2}-\frac{Z^2}{b^2} = 1$$
>   which is a **hyperbola** provided $a^2 > b^2$.

**Case III**: $Z=0$

$$\lambda^2
  \left( \frac{X^2}{a^2}+\frac{Y^2}{b^2}-1-\lambda \right) = 0$$

The double root is $\lambda=0$, the cone degenerates to a **flat plane** $z=0$.

> The vertex is any point on
>
> $$Z=0$$

**Further points to be noticed:**

The conics $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1 \cap z=0$ and $\frac{x^2}{a^2-b^2}-\frac{z^2}{b^2}=1  \cap y=0$ are known as the focal ellipse and focal hyperbola of confocal quadrics

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2+t}+\frac{y^2}{b^2+t}+\frac{z^2}{t}=1$$

where $a^2>b^2$.

See also [another answer with picture](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19849/definition-of-an-ellipsoid-based-on-its-focal-points/1837886#1837886) of mine
.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that

- the ellipse on the $x,y$ plane is symmetrical with repect to both axis, and also it is symmetrical with respect to the $z,x$ and $z,y$ planes.
- a circular cone whose axis is incident to the $x,y$ plane, will intercept on it a quadric that is symmetrical to the plane containing the cone axis and parallel to the $z$ axis.

we conclude that the axis of the cone shall lie either on the $z,x$ or in the $z,y$ plane, and so shall thus be for the vertex .

**case: cone axis in the $z,x$ plane**

Let the vertex be $V=(x_v,0,z_v)$, and the unit vector defining the axis $\mathbb {a} =(cos \alpha, 0, sin\alpha)$.
A point $P$ on the circular cone will obey to
$$
\frac{{\mathop {VP}\limits^ \to  }}
{{\left| {\mathop {VP}\limits^ \to  } \right|}} \cdot \mathbf{a} = const. = \cos \beta 
$$
and in particular a point on the $x,y$ plane will obey to:
$$
\left( {\left( {x - x_{\,v} } \right)\cos \alpha  + \left( {0 - z_{\,v} } \right)\sin \alpha } \right)^{\,2}  = \left( {\left( {x - x_{\,v} } \right)^{\,2}  + \left( {0 - z_{\,v} } \right)^{\,2}  + y^{\,2} } \right)\cos ^{\,2} \beta 
$$
that is (duly excluding the cases $\beta=\pi /2$ and $\beta=\alpha$ which can be dealt apart)
$$
\begin{gathered}
  \left( {z_{\,v} ^{\,2}  + y^{\,2} } \right)\cos ^{\,2} \beta  =  \hfill \\
   = \left( {\cos ^{\,2} \alpha  - \cos ^{\,2} \beta } \right)\left( {x - x_{\,v}  + z_{\,v} \frac{{\sin \alpha }}
{{\left( {\cos \alpha  - \cos \beta } \right)}}} \right)\left( {x - x_{\,v}  + z_{\,v} \frac{{\sin \alpha }}
{{\left( {\cos \alpha  + \cos \beta } \right)}}} \right) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
$$
\left( {1 - \frac{{\cos ^{\,2} \alpha }}
{{\cos ^{\,2} \beta }}} \right)\left( {x - x_{\,v}  - z_{\,v} \frac{{\sin \alpha }}
{{\left( {\cos \beta  - \cos \alpha } \right)}}} \right)\left( {x - x_{\,v}  + z_{\,v} \frac{{\sin \alpha }}
{{\left( {\cos \beta  + \cos \alpha } \right)}}} \right) + y^{\,2}  =  - z_{\,v} ^{\,2}  \tag{1}
$$
First step for this to represent the targeted ellipse is to get rid of the term in $x^1$, which means
that is shall be:
$$
 - x_{\,v}  - z_{\,v} \frac{{\sin \alpha }}
{{\left( {\cos \beta  - \cos \alpha } \right)}} =  - \left( { - x_{\,v}  + z_{\,v} \frac{{\sin \alpha }}
{{\left( {\cos \beta  + \cos \alpha } \right)}}} \right)
$$
i.e.
$$
 - z_{\,v} \left( {\frac{{\sin \alpha \;\cos \alpha }}
{{\cos ^{\,2} \beta  - \cos ^{\,2} \alpha }}} \right) = x_{\,v}  \tag{2}
$$
So that eq. (1) can be rewritten as:
$$
\left( {1 - \frac{{\cos ^{\,2} \alpha }}
{{\cos ^{\,2} \beta }}} \right)\left( {x + x_{\,v} \frac{{\cos \beta }}
{{\cos \alpha }}} \right)\left( {x - x_{\,v} \frac{{\cos \beta }}
{{\cos \alpha }}} \right) + y^{\,2}  =  - z_{\,v} ^{\,2} 
$$
leading to:
$$
\begin{gathered}
  \left( {1 - \frac{{\cos ^{\,2} \alpha }}
{{\cos ^{\,2} \beta }}} \right)x^{\,2}  + y^{\,2}  = x_{\,v} ^{\,2} \frac{{\left( {\cos ^{\,2} \beta  - \cos ^{\,2} \alpha } \right)}}
{{\cos ^{\,2} \alpha }} - z_{\,v} ^{\,2}  =  \hfill \\
   = x_{\,v} ^{\,2} \left( {\frac{{\left( {\cos ^{\,2} \beta  - \cos ^{\,2} \alpha } \right)}}
{{\cos ^{\,2} \alpha }} - \frac{{\left( {\cos ^{\,2} \beta  - \cos ^{\,2} \alpha } \right)^{\,2} }}
{{\sin ^{\,2} \alpha \;\cos ^{\,2} \alpha }}} \right) =  \hfill \\
   = x_{\,v} ^{\,2} \frac{{\left( {\cos ^{\,2} \beta  - \cos ^{\,2} \alpha } \right)}}
{{\cos ^{\,2} \alpha }}\frac{{1 - \cos ^{\,2} \beta }}
{{1 - \cos ^{\,2} \alpha }} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \tag{3}
$$
Comparing this to the target we obtain
$$
\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  x_{\,v} ^{\,2} \frac{{\left( {\cos ^{\,2} \beta  - \cos ^{\,2} \alpha } \right)}}
{{\cos ^{\,2} \alpha }}\frac{{\sin ^{\,2} \beta }}
{{\sin ^{\,2} \alpha }} = b^{\,2}  \hfill \\
  \left( {\frac{{\cos ^{\,2} \beta  - \cos ^{\,2} \alpha }}
{{\cos ^{\,2} \beta }}} \right) = \frac{{b^{\,2} }}
{{a^{\,2} }} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.
$$
With some algebraic manipulation
$$
\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  x_{\,v} ^{\,2} \frac{{\left( {\cos ^{\,2} \beta  - \cos ^{\,2} \alpha } \right)}}
{{\cos ^{\,2} \alpha }}\frac{{\sin ^{\,2} \beta }}
{{\sin ^{\,2} \alpha }} = b^{\,2}  \hfill \\
  x_{\,v} ^{\,2} \frac{{\cos ^{\,2} \beta }}
{{\cos ^{\,2} \alpha }}\frac{{\sin ^{\,2} \beta }}
{{\sin ^{\,2} \alpha }} = a^{\,2}  \hfill \\
  x_{\,v} ^{\,2} \frac{{\sin ^{\,2} \beta }}
{{\sin ^{\,2} \alpha }} = a^{\,2}  - b^{\,2}  \hfill \\
  \frac{{\left( {\cos ^{\,2} \beta  - \cos ^{\,2} \alpha } \right)}}
{{\cos ^{\,2} \alpha }} = \frac{{b^{\,2} }}
{{\left( {a^{\,2}  - b^{\,2} } \right)}} \hfill \\
  \left( {\frac{{\cos ^{\,2} \beta  - \cos ^{\,2} \alpha }}
{{\cos ^{\,2} \beta }}} \right) = \frac{{b^{\,2} }}
{{a^{\,2} }} \hfill \\
  \frac{{\cos ^{\,2} \beta }}
{{\cos ^{\,2} \alpha }} = \frac{{a^{\,2} }}
{{\left( {a^{\,2}  - b^{\,2} } \right)}} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.
$$
we finally arrive to rewrite the eq. (2) as:
$$
z_{\,v} ^{\,2}  = \frac{{b^{\,2} }}
{{\left( {a^{\,2}  - b^{\,2} } \right)}}\left( {1 - \frac{{\sin ^{\,2} \beta }}
{{\sin ^{\,2} \alpha }}} \right)x_{\,v} ^{\,2}  = \frac{{b^{\,2} }}
{{\left( {a^{\,2}  - b^{\,2} } \right)}}x_{\,v} ^{\,2}  - b^{\,2} 
$$
$$
\frac{{x_{\,v} ^{\,2} }}
{{\left( {a^{\,2}  - b^{\,2} } \right)}} - \frac{{z_{\,v} ^{\,2} }}
{{b^{\,2} }} = 1
$$

**case: cone axis in the $z,y$ plane**

The overall scheme is the same, just we have to exchange $x$ with $y$ and $a$ with $b$, giving
$$
\frac{{y_{\,v} ^{\,2} }}
{{\left( {b^{\,2}  - a^{\,2} } \right)}} - \frac{{z_{\,v} ^{\,2} }}
{{a^{\,2} }} = 1
$$
or if you prefer:
$$
\frac{{y_{\,v} ^{\,2} }}
{{\left( {a^{\,2}  - b^{\,2} } \right)}} + \frac{{z_{\,v} ^{\,2} }}
{{a^{\,2} }} =  - 1
$$