# Are focus and directrix for a conic section curve unique?

Tags: conic-sections

**Question.** Can a conic section curve have two distinct pairs of focus and directrix?

---

**Attempt.** I cannot think of a rigorous and logical way to convince myself of the uniqueness. But for me it is like two degrees of freedom (focus and directrix) define a single degree of freedom (a curve based on the constant eccentricity); intuitively for me, it might not be unique?

---

**Comment.** I do not need the answer to be rigorous; just some framework or hint would satisfy. Thank you!

Comment: Yes for a hyperbola.

Comment: Draw an example for each kind of conic section and think about whether the focus and directrix could have been somewhere other than where you drew them.

Comment: I tried to take a parabola, in specific $y^2=4ax$ where $a$ is a positive real, as an example; I tried to scale $a$ by some positive multiple like $2$, which would make the focus and directrix equally further away from the origin, and the equation relating $y$ and $x$ changed. Hmm, by eyeballing, parabola could have another pair of focus and directrix, but based on the equation of curve it does not seem so... @SteveKass

Comment: I'm intrigued. Let me think about it for a while. @user10354138

Comment: Ellipses and hyperbolas have two foci, each having its own directrix. That's obvious by symmetry.

Comment: Doing this just for a parabola wasn't enough. ;) For a circle, there are lots of possibilities for a directrix, and for an ellipse, there are two possibilities for the focus/directrix pair.

Answer (score 1):

We can always find the unique pair of Dandelin spheres from the conic section without ambiguity.

$\hspace{5cm}$[image]

Each Dandelin sphere touches both the right circular cone and the conic section on the corresponding focus.

See also detail discussion with animation in the link [here](https://www.gregegan.net/SCIENCE/ConicSectionOrbits/ConicSectionOrbits.html#DS) and another post of mine about focal conics and confocal quadrics [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19849/definition-of-an-ellipsoid-based-on-its-focal-points/1837886#1837886).

For a general conic, namely

$$0=
\begin{pmatrix}
  x & y & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  a & h & g \\
  h & b & f \\
  g & f & c
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  x \\ y \\ 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Its foci $z=x+yi$ are given by the complex quadratic, namely

$$Cz^2-2(G+Fi)z+(A-B)+2Hi=0$$

where capital letters $A,B, \ldots$ represent co-factors of the corresponding entries of small letters $a,b, \ldots$ of the matrix respectively.  That is

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  A & H & G \\
  H & B & F \\
  G & F & C
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
  bc-f^2 & fg-ch   & fh-bg \\
  fg-ch  & ac-g^2 & gh-af \\
  fh-bg  & gh-af    & ab-h^2
\end{pmatrix}$$

See [another post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1839510/how-to-get-the-correct-angle-of-the-ellipse-after-approximation/1840050#1840050) for finding the principal axes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Commenters have pointed out that ellipses and hyperbolae have two focus/directrix pairs.  But I assume that's not what the OP is after.

As another answer points out, given a conic you can uniquely determine its foci, center, axes, directrices, etc.

But OP would like to reconcile this with "two degrees of freedom (focus and directrix) define a single degree of freedom (a curve based on the constant eccentricity)"

For a given conic and its focus, the directrix is the [polar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Pole-polar_relation) of the focus with respect to the conic.  So the focus/directrix pair are really a single degree of freedom in this context.