# How do I find the foci of the hyperbola $x^2 + \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} x y - y^2 = 1$?

Tags: conic-sections

I have the hyperbola
$$x^2 + \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} x y - y^2 = 1$$ and I want to find the foci, but the only resources I can find that talk about finding the foci require the formula to be in standard form,
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$$

I don't think I can convert my hyperbola to standard form because it isn't purely horizontal or vertical. How do I go about finding the foci in this case?

Comment: See e.g.[this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44391/foci-of-a-general-conic-equation/2103844#2103844) or [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4022504/are-focus-and-directrix-for-a-conic-section-curve-unique/4022920#4022920) $(-\sqrt{6+3\sqrt{3}}/(2\cdot 3^\frac14),-\sqrt{6-3\sqrt{3}}/(2\cdot 3^\frac14)),
         (\sqrt{6+3\sqrt{3}}/(2\cdot 3^\frac14),\sqrt{6-3\sqrt{3}}/(2\cdot 3^\frac14))$

Answer (score 1):

Notice first of all that your hyperbola is centred at $O=(0,0)$. If $P=(x,y)$ is a vertex of the hyperbola, then the tangent at $P$ is perpendicular to $PO$, that is $y'=-x/y$. You can compute $y'$ by differentiating the equation of the ellipse:
$$
y'={x+y/\sqrt3\over y-x/\sqrt3}.
$$
Equating that to $-x/y$ gives:
$$
x^2-y^2-2\sqrt3 xy=0,
$$
which can be combined with the equation of the hyperbola to obtain
$$
P=\left(\pm\sqrt{2\sqrt3+3\over8}, \pm\sqrt{2\sqrt3-3\over8}\right).
$$

But yours is a right hyperbola (coefficients of $x^2$ and $y^2$ are opposite),
hence we immediately obtain the foci as:
$$
F=\sqrt2 P=\left(\pm\sqrt{2\sqrt3+3\over4}, \pm\sqrt{2\sqrt3-3\over4}\right).
$$

Comment: I verified that your result is correct, but I don't understand all the steps you took to get there. Could you go into more detail? Specifically, how did you get from $y'$ to $x^2 - y^2 - 2 \sqrt{3} x y = 0$, and from that to $P$?

Comment: @Lawton That's trivial algebra, I'm afraid.

Comment: Taking the idea of the axes above for $ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0$ centered in $((2cd-be)/(b^2-4ac)),-(bd-2ae)/(b^2-4ac))$ (so not a parabola):

$$y'=-(by+2ax+d)/(2cy+bx+e)=-(x-(2cd-be)/(b^2-4ac))/(y+(bd-2ae)/(b^2-4ac))$$ which in the numerator becomes $$(b^3-4abc)x^2+(-2ab^2+8a^2c+2b^2c-8ac^2)xy+(-b^3+4abc)y^2+(-2abd-2bcd+4a^2e+2b^2e-4ace)x+(-2b^2d+4acd-4c^2d+2abe+2bce)y-bd^2+2ade-2cde+be^2=0$$ i.e. a line pair; the axes of a general conic (even when the quadratic terms vanish you get the one line axis of the then parabola).